# How to convert paging element from PNG/SVG to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to convert this paging design to working CSS/JS ([see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jQBi.png)) but I don't know where to start. Any suggestions, how to do it?

P.S these numbers have to have the ability to be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers have the ability to be changed dynamically, just give ids to your div with class `text-2` and `text-5` (change the class name too), grab them with `document.getElementById("")` and change their values with `innerHTML`/`innerText`/`textContent`

Your HTML can look like this.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="pagination">
    <div class="text-2">2</div>
    <div class="text-slash">/</div>
    <div class="text-5">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Your CSS can look like this

```
.line {
    width: 2px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.pagination {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.text-2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text-slash {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.text-5 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```